# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar: sample[0].mean() y sample.mean()?

Tags: python

es mi primera pregunta. Asi que de antemano, gracias por su ayuda. Tengo una duda en la sintaxis para este ejemplo:

```
sample=pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 5, size=30))
print('sample mean is', sample[0].mean())
```

¿Qué función cumple este "**[0]**" en la segunda linea justo después de sample? o visto de otra forma, ¿Qué diferencia entre colocarlo y no colocarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes! El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toda tu pregunta, incluyendo el título

Comment: Hasta donde me da el python oxidado, pandas opera con matrices siempre, así que sample va a ser una matriz de 1xN (con suerte). Decirle que use el índice `[0]` le está diciendo que agarre esa fila y calcule la media. Probablemente el no usar el índice busque la media en toda la matriz, que haría diferencia para un sample de múltiples filas. Yo te preguntaría (porque no lo dices): ¿probaste ambas opciones? si es así, ¿qué pasó? ¿revisaste la documentación oficial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta a tu pregunta es que al no poner nombre a la columna Python le llama por defecto 0. Por tanto, con `sample[0]` estas accediendo a la columna 0, que al fin de al cabo, es tu *DataFrame* entero.

En este caso no importa que hagas la media a todo el *DataFrame*, ya que es una sola columna numérica, pero si tuvieras varias tendrías que seleccionar a que columna quieres acceder para hacer la media.

Te adjunto el enlace de la librería Pandas por si te es de utilidad: [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias. Quedo claro!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizas Pandas para generar tu DataFrame de números random generas una estructura bidimensional, donde, dependiendo de los datos que tomes, nombra estos por sus respectivas filas y columnas. En tu caso cuando imprimes la variable `sample` muestras toda la estructura de la misma. Tomando tu ejemplo pero con un número más pequeño.

```
>>sample = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 5, size = 5))
>>sample  #imprimimos la variable y nos arroja lo siguiente
           0
0   4.842824
1  13.686883
2  13.028451
3   6.135648 
4   6.837306
```

Entonces ¿Qué sucede si imprimimos `sample[0]` ? Lo siguiente.

```
>>sample[0]
0     4.842824
1    13.686883
2    13.028451
3     6.135648
4     6.837306
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Cuando usas `sample[0]` estas accediendo a los datos en el indice **0**, si quieres acceder a un dato en especifico usarías algo como `sample[0][1]` por ejemplo.

Comment: 100% entendido. Gracias.